# How do I send data to a network printer with Perl on Win32?

Tags: perl, winapi, printing

I need to print relatively complex layouts to networked/shared printers with Perl and I haven't had any luck finding modules or examples to help me in the task.  Does anyone have any links that could help me out?

I presume that what I want to do will work as Postscript.

**update**: Ok, I don't really need help with how to generate PDF or Postscript.  I'm sure that's well documented.  What I want to know is, what do I use to **send a PDF to a printer in windows from perl**.

Comment: What is a "layout"? If it is (or can be converted to) PostScript then things will be easier I suspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I still need to learn postscript or something, but I found that the following works:

```
use autodie;
use File::Copy;
copy 'C:\\frew.ps', '\\\\oxygen\\HPLJ5100 PCL6';
```

Not too complicated.  This seems to work better than `open`ing the printer and `print`ing to it.

Answer (score 3):

[Win32::Printer](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::Printer) exposes the Win32 printing API including printer selection and low level printing commands.

However, the (IMHO) easy way of printing a PDF file on any printer would be to use Ghostscript to produce PCL or PS output (depending on the language the printer supports) and then to `copy` the resulting file to the printer (using its UNC path). You may need to specify the `/b` switch for the `copy` command.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a PDF file, and the user has Adobe Reader installed (which is pretty standard), you should be able to print the file to the default printer using the [ShellExecute](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::FileOp#ShellExecute) function in [Win32::FileOp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::FileOp):

```
use Win32::FileOp 'ShellExecute';

ShellExecute(print => 'A:/Path/to/File.pdf');
```

Comment: That's good, but I need to be able to print to more than just one printer.  I'll look at the Win32::FileOp stuff though.

Answer (score -1):

Wx::Perl has very nice, liberally licensed Win32 pinting capabilities.

I haven't worked with Postscript or PDF from WxPerl, so I don't know what would be involved.  Googling wxPerl print pdf turns up [this post on the wxperl list](http://markmail.org/message/ffnz3gz53ruh4vlh#query:wxPerl%20print%20pdf+page:1+mid:uxwlszyxcttjo4wt+state:results).

> Subject:  Re: [wxperl-users] printing a
>   PDF from wxPerl   Actions... From:    Mark
>   Dootson (mark...@znix.com) Date:  Apr
>   5, 2007 5:02:40 pm
>   List: org.perl.wxperl-users
>
> Hi,
>
> After writing the last reply, a huge
>   kludge occurred to me that, as it
>   turns out, works just fine.
>
> use Wx::ActiveX::IE pass it the URL of
>   your pdf, and print merrily. e.g.

```
 my $obj = Wx::ActiveX::IE->new( $frame, -1, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize );
 $obj->LoadUrl("file:///C:/mytest.pdf");
 $obj->Print(0); # for no print dialog
 $obj->Print(1); # for print dialog
```

> Of course, loading IE and the Acrobat
>   plugin may seem a little excessive
>   just to print a doc, but heck, this is
>   windows and four lines of code is
>   pretty impressive.
>
> Mark

[This command line program](http://cybertiggyr.com/gene/psw/) might be another option.  I haven't tried it, and can't vouch for it, but it claims to work for printing postscript data to non-postscript printers.